# Django-wkhtmltopdf - dynamic templates

Tags: python, django, wkhtmltopdf, django-class-based-views

I'm wondering if it is possible to dynamically assign the `template_name` based on data provided to my class-based view using a form?

for example I have the following form page:

**views.py**

```
def form_generate_pdf(request, project_id):
   """Form to collect data to insert into PDF"""

   project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)

   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = PDFForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         request.session['field1'] = form.cleaned_data.get('field1')
         return redirect('myapp:generate_pdf')

   else:
      form = PDFForm()

   context = {
      'project': project,
      'form': form
   }
```

And the page that generates the PDF:

**views.py**

```
class Generate_PDF(PDFTemplateView):
   """Generate a PDF using the values from form_generate_pdf"""

   filename = "test.pdf"
   # I want the field below to be dynamic depending on the value of field1 from the view form_generate_pdf
   template_name = "myapp/pdf.html"
   cmd_options = {
      'page-size': 'Letter',
      'viewport-size' : '1920x1080',
      'footer-left' : '[page]/[topage]',
      'no-outline' : True,
   }

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(Generate_PDF, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      field1 = self.request.session['field1']
      context['field1'] = field1
      }
```

I would say I'm intermediate with django but I'm still fairly new to python and django in general (~5 months of playing now), I don't seem to have enough understanding to figure out how to insert some logic into the `Generate_PDF` class to programatically select the template type. Something like:

```
if field1 == 'this':
   template_name = 'myapp/pdf_1.html'
else:
   template_name = 'myapp/pdf_2.html'
```

The problem is my view can't seem to see the `field1` variable.

Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way as well. I could have my form redirect to unique class based views I suppose, but even though that would solve my issue it feels very repetitive and incorrect to me.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at more examples, documentation (sparse for the django-wkhtmltopdf module, unfortunately), and the github repository for the module; I figured out how to override the the `get_filename` and `get_template_name` function.

```
class Generate_PDF(PDFTemplateView):
   """Generate a PDF using the values from form_generate_pdf"""

   # filename = "test.pdf"
   # I want the field below to be dynamic depending on the value of field1 from the view form_generate_pdf
   # template_name = "myapp/pdf.html"
   cmd_options = {
      'page-size': 'Letter',
      'viewport-size' : '1920x1080',
      'footer-left' : '[page]/[topage]',
      'no-outline' : True,
   }

   # I found this looking at the github repository
   def get_filename(self):
     if self.field1 == 'foo':
       filename = 'bar1.pdf'
     else:
       filename = 'bar2.pdf'
     return filename

   # I found this looking at the Django documentation
   def get_template_names(self):
     if self.field1 == 'foo':
       template_name= 'myapp/bar1.html'
     else:
       template_name= 'myapp/bar2.html'
     return template_name

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(Generate_PDF, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      self.field1 = self.request.session['field1']
      context['field1'] = field1
      }
```